# Structure function solving

Tags: diagram, state-machines, transfer-function

I have following block diagram,

[image: BlockDiagram]

I am having trouble constructing structure function marks for this block diagram.
What concerns me is that OR state from State 5 to State 2 and State 6. I thought this can be written as

P(1) AND P(5) OR (P(2) AND P(6)) AND P(3) AND P(4)

but I can't evaluate it, I get lost from here... I thought first to solve in
brackets ie P(2) AND P(6) - > P(2)P(6)
But what concerns me now, is what should I first evaluate, OR statement or go as a flow goes?

Answer (score 1):

One way I see working is

```
P(1) AND ( (P(5) AND P(2)) OR (P(5) AND P(6)) ) AND P(3) AND P(4)
```

another (I think better) is

```
P(1) AND P(5) AND ( P(2) OR P(6) ) AND P(3) AND P(4)
```

Comment: OK, I have computed it and it turns out I get P(1)P(5)P(2) + P(1)P(5)P(6) - P(1)P(2)P(3)P(4)P(5)P(6) which is not correct

Comment: @user3322991 You mean that `P(1) AND P(5) AND ( P(2) OR P(6) ) AND P(3) AND P(4)` doesn't do what the block diagram shows?

Comment: @alexan_e I agree with you dude - what you say is correct. (P2 OR P6) is the only "optional" route with everything else being ANDed.